# JSON Format Error in Data Table

Tags: json

I got error like

Json data  from server could not parsed. This is caused by JSON Formating Error.

Server File

```
$details =array('name' => $rows_fetch['name'], 'latitude' => $rows_fetch['currentLatitude'], 'longitude' => $rows_fetch['currentLongitude'], 'email'=> $rows_fetch['contactEmail'], 'imei'=> $rows_fetch['imei_number'],'managerName'=> $managerName);
        array_push($device_details['devices'],$details);
$device_details['total_pages'] = $total_pages;
        $response = json_encode($device_details);
        echo $response;
```

Data Table in JS

```
$('#DataTable').dataTable( {

        "bProcessing": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp":[],
        "fnServerParams":function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
         "sServerMethod": "GET",
         "sAjaxSource": "php/totalDevices.php",
         "sAjaxDataProp": "data.inner",
         "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "details.name", "sTitle":"User Name" },
            { "mData": "details.managerName" },
            { "mData": "details.imei" },
            { "mData": "details.email" },
            { "mData": "details.latitude" }
        ],
        });
```

Comment: helpful tool: http://jsonlint.com/